# Is the new OpenAI API version backward compatible for accessing/querying GPT 3.5 Turbo?

Tags: python, openai-api, gpt-3, gpt-4

Is the new API version backward compatible for accessing/querying GPT 3.5 Turbo? For example, will code including the following tailored to the new version still work with 3.5 Turbo?

```
client = OpenAI(api_key = get_key())
response = client.chat.completions.create(
    model = model,
    messages = messages,
    max_tokens = max_tokens,
    n = n,
    stop = stop,
    temperature = temperature,
    frequency_penalty = frequency_penalty,
    presence_penalty = presence_penalty
    )
```